# Can't select correct release for branch policy

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a `Pokedex Feature Release` pipeline that has been released successfully. In my `master` branch policy I want to add that release as a requirement. So I got to `Require approval from additional services` and add policy:

But as you can see my `Pokedex Feature Release` pipeline isn't selectable.

[image]

In fact all these options are outdated. These are my current release pipelines.

[image]

I've added the `Pokedex Feature Release` pipeline manually:

[image]

And you can see it's released successfully:

[image]

But the status in the PR is not complete.

Or am I mistaken that I can use a release pipeline as a branch policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't select correct release for branch policy

I have the same issue as you before. You can check if my solution is helpful to you.

To resolve this issue, I **release the pipeline automatically instead of manually**.

Add a build policy to the branch of the pipeline, which you release it in the `Pokedex Feature Release`, then enable `Continuous deployment trigger` and `Pull request trigger`:

[image]

Then add a pull request to the branch of the pipeline, it will trigger the build and the release.

After release completed, you will see the `Pokedex Feature Release pipeline` is selectable when you add status policy for the `master` branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup. That did the trick. I figured it out yesterday :), there's no documentation (that I could find) that it was required to have the release pipeline trigger on pull request before it became available in the branch policy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to approve it first (or remove mandatory approves) and set auto-complete to true and then it will complete as soon as all the checks are completed.

Comment: The problem is not that I can't complete the pr, but that I can't select the correct release pipeline in the branch policy.

Comment: it has to be build and then it can trigger a release, i think that's how it goes

Comment: Yes, I have run the build as you can see in the screenshots. I've created a PR using the `Pokedex Feature Release` pipeline. The release has deployed successfully. I'll report this as a bug on Git then.

Comment: have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops

Comment: I did. But I reread it and found `To opt-in a stage for PR deployment, select Pre-deployment conditions for the intended stage. Inside the Triggers section, set Pull request deployment to on, which allows PR releases to be deployed to this stage. Whenever a new build is generated from a PR branch, a release is deployed to the opted-in stages and the release status is posted back to the repository.`

I changed my release pipeline to work on PR and now the pipeline is available in the policy secion

Comment: so what I said more or less

Comment: I don't see how your answer indicated changing the release pipeline trigger. That was the actual answer.

Comment: because for the pr build to trigger the release it needs the pr trigger